# Firebase Functions - Realtime Database and Transactions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have read a lot about this topic and I think that something basic is eluding me. The issue is that despite I do handle `null` values, the counted object increases randomly. For example, I have a `reports` object where I store reports. Each time one of those is created or deleted, a transaction is triggered that updates another object that holds the value of total reports (and some other stats). This count does NOT reflect the real reports count value ...

Some code (note that I did remove some for it to make it smaller):

```
'use strict';

// Firebase Functions & Admin
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const _ = require('lodash');
const moment = require('moment');

try {
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
} catch (e) {
}

exports = module.exports = functions.database.ref('/reports/{pushId}').onCreate(event => {
    let report = event.data.val();
    const collectionRef = event.data.ref.parent;

    if (report === null) {
        report = event.data.previous.val();

        if (report === null) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    let category = report.category,
        subject = report.subject,
        created_user_key = report.created_user_key;

    // count for categories
    if (typeof category !== 'undefined') {
        const countCategoryRef = collectionRef.root.child('/categories/' + category + '/reports');
        countCategoryRef.transaction(current => {
            if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
                return (current || 0) + 1;
            } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
                return (current || 1) - 1;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        });

        // count for subjects
        if (typeof subject !== 'undefined') {
            const countCategorySubjectRef = collectionRef.root.child('/categories/' + category + '/subjects/' + subject + '/reports');
            countCategorySubjectRef.transaction(current => {
                if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
                    return (current || 0) + 1;
                } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
                    return (current || 1) - 1;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // count for users
    if (typeof created_user_key !== 'undefined') {
        const countUsersRef = collectionRef.root.child('/users/' + created_user_key + '/created_reports');
        countUsersRef.transaction(current => {
            if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
                return (current || 0) + 1;
            } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
                return (current || 1) - 1;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    // count for reports_count
    const countReportsCount = collectionRef.root.child('/reports_count/' + moment().format('Y'));
    countReportsCount.transaction(current => {
        if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
            return (current || 0) + 1;
        } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
            return (current || 1) - 1;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    });

    return true;
});
```

`.onDelete()` is basically the same. Didn't want to use `.onWrite()` because I do process reports and counting would be triggered multiple times.

JSON Object (just a sample of how it looks):

```
{
  "categories" : {
    "Handhaving~2FBOA" : {
      "icon" : "assets/img/icons/deeppurple.png",
      "marker_color" : "#6200ea",
      "reports" : 7,
      "subjects" : {
        "Bijtincidenten honden" : {
          "category" : "Handhaving~2FBOA",
          "reports" : 2,
          "user_display_name" : "..",
          "user_key" : ".."
        },
        "More ...": {...}
      }
    },
    "More ...": {...}
  },
  "categories_reports" : {
    "Handhaving~2FBOA" : {
      "-LBUuwvqghbbimujwJvg" : true,
      "-LBUxS7penGMgOYkIuE7" : true,
      "-LBV5BZLzGR5ccsiG0QG" : true,
      "-LBVrBMK4y0lMD956ueE" : true,
      "-LBVwtex93d8QoESLZmm" : true,
      "-LBWhARzV1g7m3eGJ7lm" : true,
      "-LBY0q-ZVeEpk8rm6-V9" : true
    },
    "More ...": {...}
  },
  "reports" : {
    "-L9nlUmC0V_EYWLnuoJJ" : {...},
    "-L9nsxJWvQwh4MuTVXXZ" : {...},
    "-L9nuLPniqAC7gY4wkas" : {...},
    "More ...": {...}
  },
  "reports_count" : {
    "2018" : 964
  },
  "users" : {
    "41XQpZiURaZwmTNS9Ee6ulFNhRo2" : {
      "assigned_reports" : 16,
      "created_reports" : 0,
      "display_name" : "..",
      "email" : "..",
      "notes" : "",
      "rejected_reports" : 1,
      "resolved_reports" : 0,
      "type" : "admin"
    },
    "4xwxr6wPfTTaasXJeE6sdxSjefK2" : {
      "assigned_reports" : 0,
      "display_name" : "..",
      "email" : "..",
      "notes" : "",
      "rejected_reports" : 0,
      "resolved_reports" : 0,
      "type" : "viewer"
    },
    "More ...": {...}

  },
  "users_assigned_reports" : {
    "41XQpZiURaZwmTNS9Ee6ulFNhRo2" : {
      "-L9ynqHoO3C-r4TEDA_6" : true,
      "-LAHtIf6C2ji49nbmK22" : true,
      "More ...": {...}
    },
    "More ...": {...}
  },
  "users_created_reports" : {
    "C4I4djpcQLXOpnLciMTH7TPes242" : {
      "-LBWhARzV1g7m3eGJ7lm" : true,
      "-LBWhcVGV5zsfjsl1ns1" : true
    },
    "More ...": {...}
  },
  "users_resolved_reports" : {
    "6KZHvuXF29VEA0FRSptRdCMAHBo1" : {
      "-L9nsxJWvQwh4MuTVXXZ" : true,
      "-L9p86RLiNMeGF_TyzJ9" : true,
    },
    "More ...": {...}
  }
}
```

As you can see `reports_count` object claims there's 964 reports, but in reality there's only about 300.

So, how to keep transactions in order and force them to actually and properly count the added/removed objects?
Or is there a better and most importantly, more reliable way to count the actual number of reports? I thought of counting each time when a report is added/removed, that way I would be getting more reliable results, but I am afraid what will happen if two or more users create/remove reports at the same time.

Comment: Offtopic: you dont have to specify 'return true/false'. return alone is sufficient

Comment: `transaction()` returns a promise. You might want to handle those return values correctly to ensure graceful completion of the operations.